# Making a Choose file button look like a div

Tags: html, css

I've got a file submit form and I want to change how the buttons look. Previously, I've done it this way, by wrapping the form inputs into divs and then using CSS to make the divs look a certain way.

However, It doesn't seem to work for the file submit button #myFile. It just places the button inside of the div. Whereas the submit button looks how I want it to look. Anyway to fix this? I would like the Choose File button to look like the submit button. Just text, no gray oval.

[image]

```
<form id="dataform" action="submit" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="btn_upload_data">
        <input type="file" name="myfile" id="myFile"/>
    </div>
    <div id="btn_sub_data">
        <input type="submit" id="data_submit" value="Submit File"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Some CSS:

```
div#btn_upload_data input {
cursor:pointer;
padding-top:40px;
padding-bottom:60px;
width:130px;
height:0px;
background-color:#a6e79b;
border: none;
text-align:center;
display:inline-block;
float:left;
white-space: pre-wrap;    
}
```

Comment: Where's the HTML for your "Choose File" button? Where's your CSS?

Comment: Input file select fields are not possible to style.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using

```
#btn_upload_data input[type="file"] {
  opacity: 0;
  filter: aplha(opacity=0);
}
```

And then place a text inside the div as Choose File.

```
<div id="btn_upload_data" title="No File Chosen"> // if title needed
    <input type="file" name="myfile" id="myFile"/>
    Choose File...
</div>
```

There is no alternate way of editing it. It is a pre-defined input type file's style. That is set by the OS itself. So you cannot edit that! You need to override it completely.

Comment: +1 You may need to also style the height/width and or font-size of the file input to ensure it fills the entire parent container

Comment: Yes, that is just a styling propety :) Which OP can understand of doing so, once he gets the div thing working! :)